# PostgreSQL: How change date_trunc week start day from monday to another day in sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, weekday

I want to use `date_trunc` function in PostgreSQL on my datetime column to aggregate data in a week.

For example I need to get number of sales each week.

The problem is `date_trunc('week', datetime_column)` function considers Monday as the week start day and some of my customers user different start day in calendar (like Saturday).

I tried

```
 SELECT date_trunc('WEEK',(time_id + interval '2 day'))- interval '2 day' AS WEEK
```

but it's messy and I think there must be a better way.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. I don't see any cleaner way.

Comment: I fully agree with @DenysSéguret

Answer (score 3):

I needed a cleaner and easier way to tranc_date week with any week start day but considering provided solution I think my query is the best solution right now.

I think I can create a function to make it more readable but I still want a way to prevent performing 2 math operation for each record.

I will make my code the solution but I would be glad to know if there is a way to make my query faster.

```
 SELECT date_trunc('WEEK',(time_id + interval '2 day'))- interval '2 day' AS WEEK
```

Comment: So you marked your own response as a solution even when it's the same as in your quesdtion?

Comment: It has been over a year since I asked the question and I couldn't find a cleaner way. If you have a better way please add an answer! @alete

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
select
    datetime_column
    - extract(isodow from datetime_column) + 3  -- 3 is the weekday number to which we want to truncate
    - cast(extract(isodow from datetime_column) < 3 as int) * 7  -- 3 is the weekday number to which we want to truncate
from
    <table_name>
```

Comment: Thanks but my query is more efficient than yours.
I mean I wanted to prevent 2 extra math function not to add extra functions

Comment: Ok, this one just works for any day of the week to which you want cut the date (just replace 3 for integer between 1 and 7)

Answer (score 0):

try % (remainder of division)

```
select i,
       now() + make_interval(days := i) "timestamp",
       extract(dow from now() + make_interval(days := i)) day_of_week,
       (extract(dow from now() + make_interval(days := i))::int+3)%7 day_of_week_shift
    from
        generate_series(0, 6) i
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PostgreSQL, but in BigQuery it's as simple as :

SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE, WEEK(WEDNESDAY))

*replace wednesday with any other day you want your starting day to be.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't understand how _BigQuery_ can help when the question is about PostgreSQL.